# Reading value from different element

Tags: jquery

I need to come up with a way to check for a specific value withing a hidden element and if found, display a particular message. I think it can be done with a jQuery, but I am struggling with a way to do it...

Here's a simplified version of my code. I need to put a message in a TD with class 
 `outputHere`

The message is conditional, based on whether I will find class `sku` that is withing a span, that's inside a nested table, in a `TR` that is hidden...

If SKU value is found I output it, if not I look for ITEMID, and if neither is found, I put a default message...

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
   <div class="outputHere">val</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
    <table class="nested">
    <tr>
       <td>
        <span class="sku">SKU number</span>
       </td>
    </tr>
    </table> 
<tr>
  <td>
    </div>

  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

A bit overwhelmed... Thinking it should be something like:

```
$('.outputHere').each(function() {
 var $message =
 $(this).parents('table').closest('tr').find('span.sku');

if ($message) {
   $(this).text($message); } else {
    $(this).text('Default message'); 
}    
});
```

---

UPDATE

What if my SKU cell did not have a class="sku" but rather SKU number, how would I locate the SKU value then?

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
   <div class="outputHere">val</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div>
    <table class="nested">
    <tr>
       <td>
        <span class="label">SKU:</span>
       </td>
       <td>sku_value</td>
    </tr>
    </table> 
<tr>
  <td>
    </div>

  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.outputHere').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var $span = $this.closest('tr').next('tr').find('span.sku');

   if($span.html().length) {
      $this.text($span.html()); 
   } else {
      $this.text('Span Not found !!'); 
   }    
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GyLjf/)**

**UPDATED FIDDLE**

If that was the case I would use the :contains selector

```
$('.outputHere').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
    var $span = $this.closest('tr').next('tr').find('.label:contains(SKU)');

   if($span.html().length) {
       var num = $span.html().split(':')[1];
      $this.addClass('changed').text(num); 
   } else {
      $this.text('SKU Not found !!'); 
   }    
});​
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/GyLjf/1/)**

Comment: Great, thanks. Good to know I was on the right track ;) I looked at the code closer and it's worse then I originally thought... I posted an update... sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If the html structure (*although it seems a bit excessive*) is like the question then use

```
$('.outputHere').each(function() {
   var $message = $(this).closest('table').find('span.sku');

   if ($message.length) {
      $(this).text($message.text()); 
   } else {
      $(this).text('Default message'); 
   }    
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/kjcXH/

Comment: I looked at the code closer and it's worse then I originally thought... I posted an update... sorry.